# Can I change the color of the last selected face?

Tags: customization, theme

Can I change the color of the last selected face, so that it is the same as the other selected faces?

Here, I've selected the left face then the right face. Note the right face is some sort of checkered or dithered pattern, and just the outline has the nice orange 'selected' color.

[image: selected two faces]

Here I've selected the top face, note the right face has now the nice color.

[image: then selected top face]

And here I've deselected the top face. Now, both of the remaining selected faces have the nice color. This is the result I'd rather see instead of image 1.

[image: desired result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**.

In <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>*> User preferences > Themes > 3D view*:

[image]

- The *Face Selected* color controls the color of the selected face
- The *Active Vert/Edge/Face* color controls the color of the last selected face.

However, I wouldn't recommend making these colors too similar, as there are differences between the selected faces and the last selected face (active) and it might be confusing if you can't tell if a face is active or selected.

Reducing the alpha can help smooth it a little.
Comparison of default setting and with it set to the same color as selected faces:

[image] [image]

Note that this value also affects active vertices and edges as well as faces.

Comment: Thanks -- while this is better, the dithering is still there. How can I make it a smooth color, like the other selected faces?

Comment: @DavidS. AFAIK, I don't think you can, however how don't think you want these to identical (see my edit).

Comment: Yes, but it would still be nice to have a smooth color (it could be slightly different). I think it's just a lot better for the eyes without all that noise, and just more relaxing to look at a smooth color. If it indeed isn't possible to remove the dithering, I'll keep this as the accepted answer.

Comment: I don't think it is possible without modifying the source code, but reducing the alpha will help smooth some of the sharpness.